# designated initializers для шаблонного типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
inline constinit std::type_identity<T> ttag{};

template <typename Tint_type = decltype(ttag<uint64_t>)>
struct algo_config {
    bool heuristic42    = true;
    Tint_type int_type  = ttag<uint64_t>;
    size_t threads      = 4ull;
};

template <typename ...Ts>
auto algo(auto data, algo_config<Ts...> const & cfg) {
}

int main() {
    algo("data", {.int_type = ttag<uint32_t>, .threads = 8});
}
```

Почему код компилируется, если явно указать `algo_config`, но без него получаю ошибку?

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const algo_config<>&' from expression of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
```

Взято из этой статьи https://hannes.hauswedell.net/post/2023/03/30/algo_config/.

Comment: Судя по всему, аргументы функции вида `{...}` никогда не участвуют в выводе шаблонных аргументов функции. Поэтому здесь выводится `Ts = ничего`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я пробовал сделать пример проще и всё работало https://godbolt.org/z/K3Ko8G3a5

Comment: Нет, еще раз, `typename ...Ts` выводится в пустой список (и там и там). Поэтому у `algo_config` срабатывает аргумент по умолчанию (во втором примере `T = int`, который как раз подходит к вызову; а в первом примере `Tint_type = decltype(ttag<uint64_t>)`, который наоборот не подходит к вызову).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat теперь понял, можете написать ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, аргументы функций вида `{...}` никогда не участвуют в выводе шаблонных аргументов функций.

Поэтому `typename ...Ts` выводится как пустой список, и у `typename Tint_type` срабатывает аргумент по умолчанию (`decltype(ttag<uint64_t>)`).